# AuthenticationEntrypoint does not handle sophisticated AuthenticationException

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to handle sophisticated AuthenticationException raised in filter implements AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter as below.

```
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authException instanceof UsernameNotFoundException) {
      response.sendRedirect("https://myapp.com/signup");
    }
    if (authException instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
      response.sendRedirect("https://myapp.com/update/password");
    }
    if (authException instanceof LockedException) {
      response.sendRedirect("https://myapp.com/support/1");
    }
    if (authException instanceof DisabledException) {
      response.sendRedirect("https://myapp.com/support/2");
    }
    if (authException instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
      response.sendRedirect("https://myapp.com/update/account");
    }
    if (authException instanceof InsufficientAuthenticationException) {
      System.out.println("#########InsufficientAuthenticationException########");
    }
}
```

Each Exception raised from

- UserDetailsChecker:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/006b9b960797d279b31cf8c8d16f1549c5632b2c/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.java
- UserDetailsService:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/006b9b960797d279b31cf8c8d16f1549c5632b2c/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/AuthenticationUserDetailsService.java

But every time in my test, catch InsufficientAuthenticationException in MyAuthenticationEntryPoint.

This is my WebSecurityConfigurer.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class MyWebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/error");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/hello").hasRole("HELLO");
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new MyAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new MyAccessDeniedHandler());
    http.addFilter(getMyPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter());
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(getPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider());
  }

  public AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter getMyPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    var myPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter = new MyPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter();
    myPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    return myPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;
  }

  public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider getPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider() {
    var preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new MyAuthenticationUserDetailsService());
    return preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider;
  }
}
```

My guess is

1. Occur Exception in PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.
2. Set AnonymousAuthenticationToken in SecurityContext since failed authentication setting in PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
3. In FilterSecurityInterceptor, AnonymousAuthenticationToken is Denied and Keep AccessDeniedException in StackTrace
4. In ExceptionTranslationFilter, start handling Exception (AccessDeniedException) as below

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html

```
If an AccessDeniedException is detected, the filter will determine whether or not the user is an anonymous user. If they are an anonymous user, the authenticationEntryPoint will be launched. If they are not an anonymous user, the filter will delegate to the AccessDeniedHandler. By default the filter will use AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.
```

> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/006b9b960797d279b31cf8c8d16f1549c5632b2c/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java#L126

5. Finally Called sendStartAuthentication and override Exception type to InsufficientAuthenticationException

> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/006b9b960797d279b31cf8c8d16f1549c5632b2c/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java#L192

Q. How does detect Exception Type in AuthenticationEntryPoint ?

I'm trying to no authorized endpoint(etc."/world") with AuthenticationFailureHandler, Success detect Exception Type in PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.

But with authorization, I'm not sure how to detect.
Is impossible to detect Exception Type in AuthenticationEntryPoint with authorized endpoint ?

```
http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/hello").hasRole("HELLO");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you are using PreAuthenticated authentication, then there's little point in catching things like DisabledException since the authentication, by definition, was performed previously.

Comment: `by definition, was performed previously.` I know what you mean. On the condition that MyPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter was set AuthenticationFailureHandler, the above Exceptions could handled and httpServletResponse could commit in them.  and if not  AuthenticationFailureHandler, the above Exceptions wrapped by InsufficientAuthenticationException since SecurityContext has no AuthenticationToken.

Comment: In the former with above Exceptions, PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter could not break Subsequent filter. so Unfortunately, httpServletResponse was recommitted in AuthenticationEntryPoint since No Authentication in SecurityContext, then throw 500 error before return httpServletResponse.

Answer (score 1):

"response.isCommited()" with conditional in each error handler, I solved this problem, Thank you for your answer @jzheaux !